# Add null values to a datagridview

Tags: c#, nhibernate, select, datagridview, ilist

In my C# application I have a datagridview with 'person' data in it that means the datasource of this datagrisview is set with an IList of the class person.

My person model consists of the following fields (just the model, not the datagridview):

```
string foreName
string surname
int devisionId
int someOtherId
Organisation orga
```

Organisation is another model which is mapped as one-to-many with NHibernate. Among others organisation consists of the string:

```
string orgaName
```

Now comes the tricky part (for me)....
In my datagridview I dont want to have all fields of person, I just want to have the following:

```
foreName
surname
orga.orgaName
```

Getting the first twoe fields is easy:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = listOfPersons.Select(x => new { ForeName = x.ForeName, SurName = x.Surname}).ToList();
```

This works fine so far but now I also want to have the name of the organisation within my datagridview so I tried this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = listOfPersons.Select(x => new { ForeName = x.ForeName, SurName = x.Surname, OrganisationName = x.Organisation.organName}).ToList();
```

This would also work fine if every person has an organisation, but thats not the fact. Some persons do not have an organisation so 'Organisation' is null and trying to grab Organisation.organName ends with a nullpointerexeption.

The question now is:
How can I write my select-statement for the datagridview-datasource so that the organisation name is shown when Organisation is not null, otherwisesomething else is printed to the datagridview (for example: no organisation available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataGridView.DataSource = listOfPersons.Select(x => new { ForeName = x.ForeName, SurName = x.Surname, OrganisationName = x.Organisation == null ? "None" : x.Organisation.organName}).ToList();`

Comment: How can I implement the following: when organisation != null set organisation name AND set something else

Comment: You could write a function to do it and call it from within your lambda. This is probably not the best way to do it though, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A person can not only belong to an organisation, he can also belong to a devision so in the database are the two fields: organisation and devision, BUT only ONE can be set. When organsisation is set, the person just belongs to this organisation but when devision is set (organisation is null) then I also want to fill the devision in the datagridview (in the DB a devision belongs to a organisation)

Comment: so I want: listOfPersons.Select(x => new { if (x.Devision!= null) {  OrganisationName = x.Devision.Organisation.Name && DevisionName = x.Devision.Name }).ToList();

Comment: `OrganisationName = x.Organisation == null ? "None" : x.Organisation.organName, DivisionName = x.Division == null ? "None" : x.Division.divisionName`

Comment: not exactly, devision is set (automatically organisation is null then) then division name should be set by x.devision.name AND  organisation have to be set like this x.devision.organisation.name (because the devision table has a reference to a an organisation)

Comment: you can nest the logic: `OrganisationName = x.Organisation == null ? "None" : (x.Division == null ? x.Organisation.organName : x.Division.Organisation.divisionName)`

Comment: Close...after the ':' I want to excecute two statements...something like this:     x.Devision == null ? "None" : (x.Division.Organisation.organisationName & x.division.divisionname)       (When devision is NOT null then set the first column to the organisation name AND the second column to the devision name)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
dataGridView.DataSource = listOfPersons.Select(x => new { ForeName = x.ForeName, SurName = x.Surname, OrganisationName = x.Organisation != null ? x.Organisation.organName : "No organisation available"}).ToList();
```